# onConfigurationChanged() is not getting called on Android 13 and 14

Tags: android, android-activity, native, onconfigurationchanged

As per Google's Developers document,on Android 11 (API level 30) through Android 13 (API level 33), Activity.onConfigurationChanged() isn't called.[Refer this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv9NF.png)

They haven't mentioned an alternate solution to it, is anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: The alternate solution is already provided in the next paragraph in the docs screenshot you have attached.